# How to work on multiple Modules in android studio

Tags: android, import, android-studio-import

Can anyone tell me that how we will utilize the external_projects into our current project in android studio?

Basically I have a small android project for "signIn/SignUp" purposes in the running state and I want to add up that project in one of my other project. I have imported it successfully by placing it in libs folder and also have added the dependencies. So now I am confused, how i will be able to merge them. how signIn/SignUp project will run in first and then the other.

Comment: If you mean module, you can see example here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2D9lYuRECoI

Answer (score 1):

Do this

1. First start the project you want to add your sinup project to
2. go to file new and then import new module
3. when you import this project as module successfully then go to your projects activity where you want to use this projects activities or functions in and import that package there and use it as we use any other library.
4. make sure to check the manifests of both the projects of which only one project has a launcher activity either your project or the signup one based on which activity you want to start at the app launch

hope this helps

Comment: thanks @Avinash Joshi for reply, kindly tell me that how i will be able to call signIn/SignUp activity, what i will have to put in the designation adress by using intent.                           "Intent in=new Intent(this, " ? ");.

Comment: whaterEverYourActivityClassFromTheOtherModueName.class